# Fresh install of Visual Studio Express(C++) gives notes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-express

I downloaded and installed Visual Studio Express.  I created a New Project (console) called test_1.  VS popluates my project with a Hello World file with a strange (to me) include file called.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

When I click the little green arrow to run the project it asks if I want to build it and I say yes.  From there it spits out a series of errors.  The primary first few and rest look like this:

```
'test_1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test_1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
```

These look like .dll files but VS seems to want to call them PDB files.  Is there something else I need to install to get VS to run?

Comment: There are no build errors here, your project runs.

Comment: You can download the debugging symbols from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The included header is because you have probably created a project which uses so-called "precompiled headers". [See this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726155/whats-the-use-for-stdafx-h-in-visual-studio).

And the "errors" you see are not really errors. They simply state that, while you're trying to debug, debugging information (stored in [PDB files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)) cannot be found for these particular DLLs. You can obtain them from Microsoft if you really need to.

So in short, there is nothing wrong with your install of VSE and everything is as expected.

Comment: @ChrisAaker: Why is it bothering you? And "not already compiled... that the linker just linked to it" is completely non-sensical

Comment: Sorry...I have about 3 typos that make my comment unreadable...too much caffeine today.

Comment: I have done a lot of work on Windows and can't remember ever needing those PDBs.  I think the same is true for nearly everyone.