# Writing C++ in Xcode 4

Tags: c++, xcode, stdafx.h

I'm trying to learn C++ and I'm not a fan of Windows, therefore using **Visual Studio** isn't ideal. I have **Xcode** on my Mac though.

I wrote a program in C++ in Visual Studio and it works fine. When I transfer the code to Xcode (using the c++ tool environment) It still works fine but it doesn't like the top #include statement. Why?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
```

Also it still doesn't like it if I use `<...>` instead of `"..."`
It doesn't affect my current program that I can see.

Basically I'm wondering what its importance is? and do I or will I need it in the future?

Comment: remove #include "stdafx.h" its visual studio precompiled header
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726155/whats-the-use-for-stdafx-h-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

stdafx.h is a windows (visual studio) related header file. Just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

`stdafx.h` is Visual Studio's precompiled header helper. Just remove it. Xcode has its own way of doing precompiled headers.

Answer (score 0):

just like this

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <time.h>
```

`stdafx.h` only exits in vs

Answer (score 0):

After taking 2 seconds to google "stdafx" it appears it is a header file generated by visual studio.  Try removing it.  Also try searching for things.

Comment: I didn't down vote it, i don't have the correct reputation yet. 
I do however appreciate your comment, but sometimes i just want a quick answer and this site has yet to let me down.