# convert from US Dollar to EU

Tags: c++, algorithm, converters

I want make three items to calculate then convert

Example:

```
item1 + item2 + item3 = `total`
```

Then, convert `total` to Saudi riyals

// sss.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}


 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
 cout << "conver from US dollar to Saudi ryals" << endl;
 double dollars1;
 double dollars2;
 double dollars3;
 double ryals = 3.75;
 cout << "Enter the amount of money you would like to transfer item 1" << endl;
 cin >> dollars1;
 cout << "Enter the amount of money you would like to transfer item 1" << endl;
 cin >> dollars2;
 cout << "Enter the amount of money you would like to transfer item 1" << endl;
 cin >> dollars3;
 cout << "US $" << dollars1 + dollars2 + dollars3 << " equals " << ryals * (dollars1 +        dollars2 + dollars3) << " Saudi ryals." << endl;
 cout << "that's it" << endl;
 cin.get();
 cin.get();
 }
```

Comment: So exactly what part of this problem do you want help with? What multiplier to use for `Euro` vs. Ryals? Or how to add three numbers together?

Comment: #include <iostream> not "" and get rid of the rubbish any wizard has generated for you - why two main functions?!

Comment: pretty lost on this one too. But I can inform you not to put namespaces globally. Instead use std::cout, std::endl etc. make ryals a const, and try to avoid doing calculations in the output.

Comment: i mean multiple US dollar items to conver

Comment: i mean add three numbers together ^_^" @MatsPetersson

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: @user2765244: You mean like `total = item1 + item2 + item3`?

Comment: @GeneParmesan Making `ryals` a const probably isn't a good idea, since in practice, you'll want to read the value from a configuration file, or over a socket from a server.  (This is an old example of "one man's constant is another man's variable".  And a very strong argument against distinguishing between constants and variables in your naming convention.)

Answer (score 1):

Today's exchange rate for US dollar to Saudi riyal is $1 US to 3.75 riyal.

Your logic seems correct here : `ryals * ( dollars1 + dollars2 + dollars2)` but you for starters have two mains. This cannot happen in any circumstance. Also I'd re-think your naming convention of `dollars1, dollars2, dollars3`

Your `#include <stdafx>` was auto generated by Visual Studio, which is why I'm assuming two mains were created for you. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726155/whats-the-use-for-stdafx-h-in-visual-studio) for more information.

Try this:

```
#include "iostream"

     using namespace std;
     int main()
     {
     cout << "conver from US dollar to Saudi ryals" << endl;
     double dollars1;
     double dollars2;
     double dollars3;
     double ryals = 3.75;
     cout << "Enter the amount of money you would like to transfer item 1" << endl;
     cin >> dollars1;
     cout << "Enter the amount of money you would like to transfer item 1" << endl;
     cin >> dollars2;
     cout << "Enter the amount of money you would like to transfer item 1" << endl;
     cin >> dollars3;
     cout << "US $" << dollars1 + dollars2 + dollars3 << " equals " << ryals * (dollars1 +        dollars2 + dollars3) << " Saudi ryals." << endl;
     cout << "that's it" << endl;
     cin.get();

 }
```