# Build open62541 DLL with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, c, dll, opc-ua, open62541

Hello community I would like to write UI for OPC UA server using open62541 lib.
The input off software should read text file and cast data throe server to already available client.

Stuck at stage where need compile dll file for further using it in windows forms project.

There is some info mentioned that Davy Triponney compiled it with Visual C++ 2013
https://github.com/open62541/open62541/wiki/Using-open62541-from-C%23

But I have no luck with VS 2017.

There is sequence of my progress:

- Already downloaded .h and .c windows 64 bit files from https://open62541.org/
- Created Dynamic-Link Library(DLL) project.
- Attached .h and .c files to project, selected 64 compiler:

[image: Project]

Getting lot warnings and fault on build:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C4005   'CLOSESOCKET': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39113   
Warning C4005   '_Q_INVALIDATE': macro redefinition open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 130 
Warning C4005   'UA_atomic_sync': macro redefinition    open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 813 
Warning C4005   'UA_atomic_sync': macro redefinition    open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 815 
Warning C4005   'CLOSESOCKET': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 35386   
Warning C4005   'errno__': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 35387   
Warning C4005   'CLOSESOCKET': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39088   
Warning C4005   'CLOSESOCKET': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39106   
Warning C4005   'UA_sleep_ms': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39111   
Warning C4005   'UA_sleep_ms': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39127   
Warning C4005   'UA_sleep_ms': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39130   
Warning C4005   'WIN32_INT': macro redefinition open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39135   
Warning C4005   'OPTVAL_TYPE': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39136   
Warning C4005   'ERR_CONNECTION_PROGRESS': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39137   
Warning C4005   'UA_fd_set': macro redefinition open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39167   
Warning C4005   'UA_fd_isset': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39168   
Warning C4005   'errno__': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39176   
Warning C4005   'errno__': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39181   
Warning C4005   'INTERRUPTED': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39182   
Warning C4005   'WOULDBLOCK': macro redefinition    open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39183   
Warning C4005   'AGAIN': macro redefinition open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 39184   
Warning C4005   'ANSI_COLOR_RED': macro redefinition    open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 40158   
Warning C4005   'ANSI_COLOR_GREEN': macro redefinition  open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 40159   
Warning C4005   'ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW': macro redefinition open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 40160   
Warning C4005   'ANSI_COLOR_BLUE': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 40161   
Warning C4005   'ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA': macro redefinition    open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 40162   
Warning C4005   'ANSI_COLOR_CYAN': macro redefinition   open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 40163   
Warning C4005   'ANSI_COLOR_RESET': macro redefinition  open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 40164   
Warning C4005   'BEGIN_CRITSECT': macro redefinition    open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 40709   
Warning C4005   'END_CRITSECT': macro redefinition  open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 40710   
Error   C1010   unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?    open62541   c:\users\scadaadmin\desktop\open62541-win64\open62541.c 43979
```

The question is how property I can compile open62541 c code dll file with Visual Studio 2017 to able use it in a windows forms C# application as server?

Comment: The warnings I do not think are important.  It is the last line.  Did you open  open62541.c and check line : 43979?

Comment: This is probably related to the architecture selection.
If POSIX is selected for the architecture, then win32 will not work.
The official single-file downloads seem to be for POSIX.

There is only one solution:
Add all the architectures in the amalgamation.
And wrap them with a conditional (ifdef) so that only the detected architecture is used.

That means we need to additionally detect the architecture with macros. But how actually do that?

Comment: Did you open the file like I said?  Probably sound like you did do what I suggested.

Comment: Line 43979 is end of .c file also i found a Article about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113280/fatal-error-c1010-stdafx-h-in-visual-studio-how-can-this-be-corrected .. but when i set up a no use Precompiled Headers more errors apears.

Comment: What were the new errors?  What is the line at 43979?

Comment: Problem solved. We need use CMake to port project for visual studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the project open62541 has been updated I suggest you take directly the current state of the sources. This way you will be able to better use the examples they provide. Here is the howto for building the project. Maybe it could be simpler but I encountered quite a lot of problems so I give you all the steps I did.

---

## PREPARING THE ENVIRONMENT

1. Install cmake (with the PATH update)

https://cmake.org/download/

2. Install a recent version of python (with the PATH update)

https://www.python.org/downloads/

3. Reopen your session so that the new PATH variables are taken into account
4. Install the python module "six"

pip install six

## BUILDING MBEDTLS

1. Download the sources of the library (apache license)

https://tls.mbed.org/download

2. Run cmake in the sources

```
cmake . -DUSE_SHARED_MBEDTLS_LIBRARY=ON -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

3. Open "mbed TLS.sln" with Visual Studio (I am using Community 2015) and generate everything in "Release" mode
4. Copy the following files

   - libraries .lib from "library\Release" to "Path\To\OpcUa_lib"
   - binaries .dll from "library\Release" to "Path\To\OpcUa_bin"
   - the folder "mbedtls" in "include" to "Path\To\OpcUa_include"

## BUILDING OPEN62541

1. Clone the open62541 repository to get the sources (with GitHub desktop or command line)

https://github.com/open62541/open62541

2. Create a folder "build" in the sources (for example C:\Users\Davy\Documents\GitHub\open62541\build)
3. Open a terminal in the "build" folder and run cmake (adapt \path\To... first)

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -DUA_ENABLE_ENCRYPTION=ON -DUA_ENABLE_AMALGAMATION=ON -DMBEDTLS_INCLUDE_DIRS="Path\To\OpcUa_include" -DMBEDTLS_LIBRARY="Path\To\OpcUa_lib" -DMBEDX509_LIBRARY="Path\To\OpcUa_lib" -DMBEDCRYPTO_LIBRARY="Path\To\OpcUa_lib" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DUA_LOGLEVEL=100
```

4. Open the solution "build\open62541.sln" with Visual Studio (Community 2015) and add "mbedcrypto.lib", "mbedtls.lib" and "mbedx509.lib" as resources for the linker in the project "open62541/lib/open62541"

   - right click on "open62541/lib/open62541", select "properties"
   - go to "Linker" => "General"
   - add "Path\To\OpcUa_lib" as additional directory for the dependencies
   - go to "Linker" => "Entry"
   - add three lines with "mbedcrypto.lib", "mbedtls.lib" and "mbedx509.lib" in "Additional dependencies"
5. Generate "open62541/lib/open62541" in "Release" mode
6. You can now use the following files

   - the library "build\bin\Release\open62541.lib"
   - the binary "build\bin\Release\open62541.dll"
   - the file "build\open62541.h"

## INTEGRATION IN ANOTHER PROJECT

You will need to reference the amalgamated .h of open62541 and add these dependencies in the linker: open62541.lib, mbedcrypto.lib, mbedtls.lib, mbedx509.lib, Ws2_32.lib. I also had to specify the platform Visual Studio 2013 (v120) in the project properties.