# stdafx.h to header files

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I have `MyClass.cpp` and `MyClass.h` files. Since `MyClass.cpp` has `#include "MyClass.h"` I put `stdafx.h` to  `MyClass.h`. During compile I got error:

> unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?

Why? If `MyClass.cpp` includes `MyClass.h` it should include all lines of `MyClass.h` and these lines contain `stdafx.h`.

Comment: The command line to the compiler will include `/Yu"stdafx.h"`, so then "stdafx.h" must be the first header found, otherwise it throws error `C1010`

Comment: See: [What's the use for “stdafx.h” in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4726838/868014)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you put `#include "stdafx.h"` inside your .h file. The compiler doesn't care. It wants to see `#include "stdafx.h"` as the first line of your .cpp file, unless you have "Not using precompiled headers" as a compiler option for your source file.. The reasoning has to do with precompiled headers. I cannot really offer a technical explanation, but simply doing it that way will make life easier.

Answer (score 1):

It is the other way around if you want `MyClass.h` to be precompiled.

- `MyClass.h` doesn't include `stdafx.h`
- `stdafx.h` include `MyClass.h`
- `MyClass.cpp` include `stdafx.h` as the first directive. For code clarity, it may also include `MyClass.h`.