# Is it allowed to include a precompiled header into a header file?

Tags: c++, precompiled-headers, pch

I know what `precompiled headers` are, but I found nothing about `pch`-s being included in `header` files. Can you do that? I tried it and it worked. Does it have some drawbacks?

Comment: It depends on your compiler. Precompiled headers are not part of standard C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that. Just check to see if your compile times actually go down.

This question is similar.
[stdafx.h to header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451219/stdafx-h-to-header-files)