# quickfix library step-by-step successful installation for windows python user

Tags: python

I have Windows 7, 64 bit

`pip install quickfix` meets the following errors:

https://gyazo.com/631c0478f9d65da8f63640772c80b1d0

I tried to download the quickfix and add the folder to my python IDE.
When I call quickfix I get the following:

https://gyazo.com/b997fbcda945a67f859cc8c1f25d083d

What I want, and I am a beginner, is to install it so that I can use it in python.

What is the easiest step-by-step way to do so?

Please guide me in the clearest way possible,
Thanks!

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using Anaconda, so try installing your package with `conda` instead of `pip`. The conda forge provides pre-built package for your architecture, which do not require a build environment. See https://anaconda.org/josh/quickfix

Comment: Hi,
conda not working:

Comment: Conda not working: https://gyazo.com/4aed74690c00ea8801c61d03994f6646

Answer (score 4):

You can find (untested) pre-built Windows version of `quickfix` here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#quickfix

Download the appropriate version, e.g., `quickfix‑1.15.1‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl` if you are using python 2.7 on Windows 64 bits, and then install it using:

```
pip install quickfix‑1.15.1‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but where should I place the .whl? Does it matter?

Comment: @DavideTessarollo Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I have both 2.7 and 3.7, I can try with them both. So I did

Comment: Ok, now apparently worked with
quickfix‑1.15.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl

Comment: @DavideTessarollo looks like your pip defaults to python 3, but this is a 32bits version.

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this so many times.  There is a bug in setup.py in version 1.15.1. What worked for me was to pip install quickfix==1.14.1 and it worked.

This is especially useful for all for those using python on mac!  All the answers and links are to download and install a win wheel.  That doesn't help mac users.  pip install 1.14.1 should solve this for other mac users.