# fatal error in vc++ while running c++ program

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new to vc++.

```
#include<iostream.h>

void main()
{
    cout<<"hi this is vc++";
}
```

> Compiling...
>
> h.cpp
>
> c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\myprojects\new1\h.cpp(7) :
>   fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for
>   precompiled header directive Error executing cl.exe.
>
> h.obj - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

Comment: Two significant problems with your code. First, `void main` is wrong. The correct return type is `int`, so it is always prototyped as `int main`. Second, you need to be using `std::cout`. The code shown here wouldn't compile, unless you had `using namespace std;` somewhere, which is not something you should really be doing.

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++ uses precompiled headers by default, this feature speeds up compilation but it means you need to have a #include "stdafx.h" at the top of your cpp files.

An alternative is to turn off precompiled headers. Here is how to do it ([source and more detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4726838/70365)):

> In Visual Studio 2010, this setting is controlled from the GUI via Right-clicking on a CPP Project, selecting 'Properties' and navigating to "Configuration Properties\C/C++\Precompiled Headers". For other versions of Visual Studio, the location in the GUI will be different.