# unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. did you forget to add #include stdafx.h to your source?

Tags: c++

So this is my code, I keep getting "unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. did you forget to add #include stdafx.h to your source?" so I added it to all headers and files and it still says that same error. How do I get rid of the error?

P.S. if you dont mind checking to see if this code answers these questions(The multiplication and division overloading I barely started, but the relational and equality should be ok)

- overload the * multiplication operator
- overload the / division operator
- overload all the relational and equality operators

Hugeint.h

```
#ifndef HUGEINT_H
#define HUGEINT_H

#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h";

class Hugeint
{
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Hugeint &);
public:
static const int digits = 30; 

Hugeint(long = 0); 
Hugeint(const std::string &); 


Hugeint operator+(const Hugeint &) const;
Hugeint operator+(int) const;
Hugeint operator+(const std::string &) const;

Hugeint operator*(const Hugeint &) const;
Hugeint operator/(const Hugeint &) const;

//relation
bool operator<(const Hugeint &) const;
bool operator<=(const Hugeint &) const;
bool operator>(const Hugeint &) const;
bool operator>=(const Hugeint &) const;
//equal
bool operator==(const Hugeint &) const;
bool operator!=(const Hugeint &) const;


private:
std::array< short, digits > integer;
//short arrayInt[ max ];
}; 

#endif
```

Hugeint.cpp

```
#include <cctype>
#include "HugeInt.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;


Hugeint::Hugeint(long value)
{

for (int i = 0; i<digits; i++)
    integer[i] = 0;


for (size_t j = digits - 1; value != 0 && j >= 0; --j)
{
    integer[j] = value % 10;
    value /= 10;
} 
} 

Hugeint::Hugeint(const string &number)
{

for (int i = 0; i<digits; i++)
    integer[i] = 0;

size_t length = number.size();

for (size_t j = digits - length, k = 0; j < digits; ++j, ++k)
    if (isdigit(number[k])) 
        integer[j] = number[k] - '0';

} 

Hugeint Hugeint::operator+(const Hugeint &op2) const
{
Hugeint temp; 
int carry = 0;

for (int i = digits - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    temp.integer[i] = integer[i] + op2.integer[i] + carry;

    if (temp.integer[i] > 9)
    {
        temp.integer[i] %= 10; 
        carry = 1;
    }
    else 
        carry = 0;
} 

return temp; 
} 


Hugeint Hugeint::operator+(int op2) const
{

return *this + Hugeint(op2);
} 

Hugeint Hugeint::operator+(const string &op2) const
{

return *this + Hugeint(op2);
} 



bool Hugeint::operator<(const Hugeint &hugeInt) const
{
bool less = false;
for (int i = digits - 1; i >= 0 && !less; --i)
{

    if (integer[i] <hugeInt.integer[i])
    {
        less = true;
    } 
} 

return less;


}

bool Hugeint::operator<=(const Hugeint &hugeInt) const
{
bool LessThan = false;
for (int i = digits - 1; i >= 0 && !LessThan; --i)
{

    if (integer[i] <= hugeInt.integer[i])
    {
        LessThan = true;
    } 

} 

return LessThan; 
}

bool Hugeint::operator>(const Hugeint &hugeInt) const
{
bool greater = false;
for (int i = digits - 1; i >= 0 && !greater; --i)
{

    if (integer[i] >hugeInt.integer[i])
    {
        greater = true;
    } 

} 

return greater; 
}

bool Hugeint::operator>=(const Hugeint &hugeInt) const
{
bool GreaterThan = false;
for (int i = digits - 1; i >= 0 && !GreaterThan; --i)
{

    if (integer[i] >= hugeInt.integer[i])
    {
        GreaterThan = true;
    }

} 

return GreaterThan; 

}

bool Hugeint::operator==(const Hugeint &hugeInt) const
{
bool eqaul = true;
for (int i = digits - 1; i >= 0 && eqaul; --i)
{

    if (integer[i] != hugeInt.integer[i])
    {
        eqaul = false;
    }

} 

return eqaul; 
}


ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, const Hugeint &num)
{
size_t i;

for (i = 0; (i < Hugeint::digits) && (0 == num.integer[i]); ++i); 

if (i == Hugeint::digits)
    output << 0;
else
    for (; i < Hugeint::digits; ++i)
        output << num.integer[i];

return output;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include "Hugeint.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;


int main(){
char value1[30];
char value2[30];

cout << "enter HugeInt1 : ";
cin >> value1;

Hugeint hugeInt1(value1);

cout << "enter HugeInt2 : ";
cin >> value2;

Hugeint hugeInt2(value2);

cout << "< opertor " << endl;
if (hugeInt1 < hugeInt2) {
    cout << hugeInt1 << " is less than " << hugeInt2 << endl;
}
else {
    cout << hugeInt1 << " is not less than " << hugeInt2 << endl;
}
cout << "<= opertor " << endl;
if (hugeInt1 <= hugeInt2) {
    cout << hugeInt1 << " is less than or eqaul " << hugeInt2 << endl;
}
else {
    cout << hugeInt1 << " is not less than or equal " << hugeInt2 << endl;
}
cout << "> opertor " << endl;
if (hugeInt1 > hugeInt2) {
    cout << hugeInt1 << " is greater than " << hugeInt2 << endl;
}
else {
    cout << hugeInt1 << " is not greater than " << hugeInt2 << endl;
}
cout << ">= opertor " << endl;
if (hugeInt1 >= hugeInt2) {
    cout << hugeInt1 << " is greater than or eqaul " << hugeInt2 << endl;
}
else {
    cout << hugeInt1 << " is not greater than or equal " << hugeInt2 << 
endl;
}
cout << "== opertor " << endl;
if (hugeInt1 == hugeInt2) {
    cout << hugeInt1 << " is eqaul to " << hugeInt2 << endl;
}
else {
    cout << hugeInt1 << " is not equal to " << hugeInt2 << endl;
}
system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the use for "stdafx.h" in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726155/whats-the-use-for-stdafx-h-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Don't put `#include "stdafx.h";` in a header. Put it in the CPP files. And make sure it is the first include. Everything above the stdafx is ignored.

Answer (score 4):

`#include "stdafx.h"` must be the **first** include in every source file that is configured to *use* the precompiled header (delete your extraneous `;` character by the way). These files must have the `-Yu` compilation flag.

There must also be a single source file that *creates* the precompiled header. Traditionally this is called `stdafx.cpp` and only contains the single line `#include "stdafx.h"`. This file must have the `-Yc` compilation flag.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio you could create C++ project -> EmptyProject and than just add main.cpp file with `int main() {}` function. In that case all be work fine, and no precompiled headers needed.