# fstream is not working in Visual Studio 2017 even after including the std namespace

Tags: c++, file-handling

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.txt");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying out basic file handling in c++ using visual studio 2017, can't seem to use the class fstream

> error - Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2065   'myfile': undeclared identifier CSV C:\Users\User\source\repos\CSV\CSV\CSV.cpp  11
>   Error   C2065   'ofstream': undeclared identifier   CSV C:\Users\User\source\repos\CSV\CSV\CSV.cpp  8
>   Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'myfile'    CSV C:\Users\User\source\repos\CSV\CSV\CSV.cpp  8
>   Error   C2065   'myfile': undeclared identifier CSV C:\Users\User\source\repos\CSV\CSV\CSV.cpp  8
>   Error   C2065   'myfile': undeclared identifier CSV C:\Users\User\source\repos\CSV\CSV\CSV.cpp  9
>   Error   C2228   left of '.open' must have class/struct/union    CSV C:\Users\User\source\repos\CSV\CSV\CSV.cpp  9
>   Error   C2065   'myfile': undeclared identifier CSV C:\Users\User\source\repos\CSV\CSV\CSV.cpp  10
>   Error   C2228   left of '.close' must have class/struct/union   CSV C:\Users\User\source\repos\CSV\CSV\CSV.cpp  11

what should I do ?

Comment: Turn off *pre-compiled headers*, remove `#include "stdafx.h"`

Comment: Why are you guys answering in the comments section? This is not a chat room or a message board/forum. Thanks.

Comment: It's a close call, when the answer is of the type that can be found at the beginning of any tutorial, and its of marginal use to other readers, a quick comment will at times suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler ignores everything before `#include "stdafx.h"` so move that line above the other include directives.

Comment: Thanks it worked out... btw why is the stdafx.h file needed in visual studio ?

Comment: @PranavLokhande: This other answer should help: [What's the use for “stdafx.h” in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4726838/445976). Note that precompiled headers are *optional* and you can decide not to use them if you wish.