# For header file # include "stdafx.h" getting error message no such file or directory , for newly created project in Visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2015, header-files

For project created in visual studio 2015,
Source file Code contains code line having #include "stdafx.h"
But in header file no file is added.

After building the solution error message is stdafx: no such file or directory.
How to resolve this issue??

Tried adding header file named stdafx.h

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "stdafx.h" used for in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726155/what-is-stdafx-h-used-for-in-visual-studio)

Comment: You must specify every directory with your h-files here: Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories

Comment: Did  you create the project from Visual  Studio  template? What project did you create,  MFC?

Comment: Was your problem solved? What kind of project did you create?