# Why are all cout's and cin's "undeclared identifiers

Tags: c++

In my main.cpp all of my cout's and cin's have errors.

```
/**
* Description: This program demonstrates a very basic String class.  It creates
* a few String objects and sends messages to (i.e., calls methods on)
* those objects.
*
*/
//#include <iostream>
#include "mystring.h"
//using namespace std;

/* Function Prototypes */

void Display(const String &str1, const String &str2, const String &str3);


/*************************** Main Program **************************/

int main()
{
  String str1, str2, str3;   // Some string objects.
  char s[100];               // Used for input.

  // Print out their initial values...

 cout << "Initial values:" << endl;
 Display(str1, str2, str3);
```

My main.cpp cannot not be changed, so my question is, how can I fix this error, what do I have to add to my header file and implementation file?

Comment: Because you've commented out both `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;`?

Comment: Related post - [error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1868603/465053)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In my main.cpp all of my cout's and cin's have errors.

You simply need to `include <iostream>` header file, and use `std` with `cout` and `cin`:

```
#include <iostream>
//^^
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Initial values: "<< std::endl;
    //^^
}
```

Comment: wow, I feel stupid but instead of using std, can't I just use
using namespace std;?

Comment: @Joe You can do `using namespace std`, but it is considered bad practice. so it is better to use `std::cout`

Comment: @Joe: Just to further elaborate, there is a good reason why you shouldn't use that. Say you download a C++ library that has a cout function. The compiler could confuse the two. And, if you liked this answer, you should accept it.

Comment: Hmm, thats pretty neat, I never knew that "using namespace std;" could have a draw back.

Answer (score 4):

You have `iostream` header commented out here:

```
//#include <iostream>
```

You also need to add `std::`, this:

```
cout << "Initial values:" << endl;
```

should be:

```
std::cout << "Initial values:" << std::endl;
```

I see that you have `using namespace std;` commented out. I would advise against `using namespace std;`, it may save you some typing but it is [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and can cause problem later on.

Comment: @NathanS. Indeed, that is what I get for hand editing instead of just copying and pasting from code I edited and compiled.