# Error: 'cout' : undeclared identifier; though I've included iostream header file in program

Tags: c++, namespaces, iostream, cout

I am trying to compile the simple program below. But, it's not compiling & gives error:

```
error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
```

I want to ask you that why this program doesn't work though I've included `iostream` header file in it?

```
#include <iostream>

void function(int) { cout << “function(int) called” << endl; }
void function(unsigned int) { cout << “function(unsigned int) called” << endl; }
    int main()
    {
        function(-2);
        function(4);
        return 0;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `std::cout` instead of `cout` only. Append `std::` before everything you use from `namespace std`.

Comment: Or in a case like this - when you write a very simple program, you can always write `using namespace std;` somewhere below your `#include <iostream>`. It will inform the compiler to look for `cout` in std namespace, thus allowing your `cout` to work.

Although this is considered a bad practice whatsoever.

Comment: Avoid `using namespace std;`. That is guaranteed to bite you one day. If you don't want to type `std::cout`, use `using std::cout`, but limit it to a small scope, and don't use it in headers.

Comment: There is more on the `using namespace std` issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1868603/608639)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The cout stream is defined in the std namespace. So to name it you write:

```
std::cout
```

If you want to shorten this to cout then you can write

```
using namespace std;
```

or

```
using std::cout;
```

before writing cout.

Any good documentation source will tell you which namespace contains an object. For instance: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout

Comment: Side comment: Don't use `using namespace std`. If you use this atrocity in a header, users of that header will come for your head. The consequences are less severe if you use this in a source file. Reviewers of that file will regard the author as a hopeless newb. Even `using std::cout` is dubious. I, for one, like to see that `std::<whatever>`. It tells me that `<whatever>` is from the standard library.

Comment: @Mona std::cout is part of the C++ standard library and so not available in C code

Comment: @DavidHammen please could you clarify - what is dubious about `std::cout` and what do you prefer?

Comment: @DavidHammen Apologies - there was too much sun on my screen and I saw "`using std::cout` is dubious" as "using `std::cout` is dubious"!

Answer (score 2):

You have to write `std::cout` or add `using std;`