# What is the relationship between iostream and namespace std?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

I am currently using *Teach Yourself C++ in 21 Days, Second Edition* book to learn about C++ coding, along with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express. At the end of Chapter 1, there is a small exercise about writing and compiling the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Quite simple, right? However to my surprise the code would not compile, due to this error:

> error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier

I began scouring the Web, and soon found some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868603/error-c2065-cout-undeclared-identifier). Turns out I had to add
`using namespace std;` to my code!

However there was no mention of namespaces in the book, so I figured the book is outdated. (It uses `#include <iostream.h>` pre-processor directive!) After some more Web research I found a lot of information about namespaces, `namespace std`, along with some historical background on `<iostream.h>` and `<iostream>`, and all this flow of new information is quite confusing to me. (Not to mention all the unnecessary Google results about medical STDs...)

So here are some questions I've got so far:

1. If I am including the `iostream` library, why is a `namespace` needed to find `cout`? Is there another `cout` somewhere that could cause a name clash? If someone could provide a diagram for this, that'd be great.

And as a bonus, some historical background:

1. What exactly was `iostream.h` before it was changed to `iostream`?
2. Did `namespace` play a part in this change?

Comment: You did not have to add `using namespace std;` to your code. You had to say `std::cout`, or `using std::cout;` inside of `main`.

Comment: But why is the `std` part even needed? Are there several `cout`s inside `iostream`?

Comment: Because `cout` is inside the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All of the standard library definitions are inside the namespace std. That is they are not defined at global scope, so in order to use them you need to qualify them in one of the following way:

- `std::cout`
- `using namespace std`
- `using std::cout`

For instance lets take this:

```
// declarations
int global_variable;

namespace n {
int variable2;
}
```

`global_variable` can be access as it is:

```
int x;
x = global_variable;
```

But variable2 is not part of the global space, but part of the `namespace n`.

```
int x;
x = variable2; // error variable2 identifier not found.
```

So you have to use the fully qualified name:

```
int x;
x = n::variable2;
```

As a shortcut you can write:

```
using namespace n;
int x;
x = variable2; // variable2 is searched in current namespace
               // and in all namespaces brought in with using namespace
               // Found ONLY in namespace n -> OK
```

or

```
using n::variable2; // this makes any unqualified reference to `variable2`
                    // to be resolved to `n::variable2`
int x;
x = variable2;
```

As for the header files, `iostream.h` was used by many compilers before there was a standard. When the committee tried to standardize they decided to make the C++ headers extensionless in order not to break compatibility with existing code.

Answer (score 7):

Because this line starts with `#`, it is called a "preprocessor directive". The preprocessor
reads your program before it is compiled and only executes those lines beginning with `#`. The preprocessor sets up your source code for the compiler.

The `#include` directive causes the preprocessor to include the contents of another file into the program.  The `iostream` file contains code that allows a C++ program to display output to the screen and take input from the keyboard. The `iostream` files are included in the program at the point the `#include` directive appears. The `iostream` is called a header file and appears at the top or head of the program.

**`using namespace std;`**

C++ uses namespaces to organize names or program entities. It declares that the program will be assessing entities who are part of the `namespace` called "std."  Every name created by the `iostream` file is part of that `namespace`.

Answer (score 4):

> *1.If I am including the `iostream` library, why is a `namespace` needed to find `cout`? Is there another `cout` somewhere that could cause a name clash?*

It is needed because the C++ standard requires that `cout` be inside the `std` namespace. There *could* be a clashing `cout`, but not in the standard library (e.g. your own code, or some third party library.)

> *1.What exactly was `iostream.h` before it was changed to `iostream`?*

It could be anything, because it is not part of the standard, but it was the name of a pre-standardization header which formed the basis for `iostream`. Usually, it declared all names in the global namespace, so it is likely that the example you are looking at was written pre-standardization.

*2.Did `namespace` play a part in this change?*

This question is unclear. The keyword `namespace` may be used inside implementations, and it is used to declare and define data, functions, types etc. inside a namespace. So it did have *some* part in this change.

```
namespace foo
{
  void bar();  // declares foo::bar
}
```

Comment: _It is needed because the C++ standard requires that `cout` be inside the `std namespace`. There could be a clashing `cout`, but not in the standard library (e.g. your own code, or some third party library.)_     



How does `cout` stay inside `std` namespace? The whole implementation or definitions of `cout`?

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you can logically group identifiers into [namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).
`cout` stream is inside namespace std. You can use it in 3 ways.

1. Write `using namespace std` at top and use `cout` as you did.
2. Write `using std::cout` at top and use `cout` as you did.
3. Use `std::cout` instead of `cout`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @bolov ..to understand the point referring this [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream), this is the declaration:

```
#include <ios>
#include <streambuf>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

namespace std 
{
    extern istream cin;
    extern ostream cout;
    extern ostream cerr;
    extern ostream clog;

    extern wistream wcin;
    extern wostream wcout;
    extern wostream wcerr;
    extern wostream wclog;
}
```

Comment: Use three backticks (```) to create a code block. Align your code to make it more readable. Explain why the standard is using its own namespace (`std`): because this way user code can have its own facilities with the same name in the global namespace, and the names won't conflict with the standard headers' names.

Answer (score 0):

With new version of c++ namespace was included. iostream contains all the declarations for input and output. Namespace std is used to tell that we are using cout and cin which were part of std namespace. You can create your own variables named cout and cin in your own namespace.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question as you. I am just going to teach you in laymen terms.

Imagine that you need a pencil which is placed in a drawer which is present in your bedroom. So you need to enter in your room to access your pencil. Here room is **iostream**. After you entered your room, you need to open the drawer and access the pencil. Here drawer is **namespace** and pencil is **cin/cout**.

Reference:- https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/Introduction