# Why the compiler can't find class std::ifstream?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a VS2013 VC++ project that I want to create a std::ifstream object like below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream f;
    return 0;
}
```

It works as expcted but if I change the header included order the compiler will issue an error:

```
#include <fstream>
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream f;
    return 0;
}
```

```
error C2065: 'ifstream' : undeclared identifier
```

What's in the stdafx.h file is very simple:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

My problem is why the header included order affects the compiler to find std::ifstream? Is there any macro defined in other headers included by stdafx.h affects the result? But when I press F12 on ifstream class and jump to the definition the class is not grayed out which means they are enabled and the compiler can find them right? I have google for a while but still can't figure out why it compiles fail.

Comment: alternative dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868603/error-c2065-cout-undeclared-identifier

Comment: All `#include`s before `#include "stdafx.h"` are ignored.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will search more about this.